# Smallest known formula for the determinant

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, algebraic-complexity, determinant

The smallest known formula for the determinant has size $n^{\mathcal O(\log n)}$ according to the folklore (or to Ran Raz in its paper *[Multi-Linear Formulas for Permanent and Determinant are of Super-Polynomial Size](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2003/067/)*).

Do you have any reference for this? In particular, what is this formula?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is described in Berkowitz, [*On computing the determinant in small parallel time using a small number of processors*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019084900188) (see also Soltys, [*Berkowitz's algorithm and clow sequences*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201315)). Another way is described in Hrubeš and Tzameret, [*Short proofs for the determinant identities*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.6265).

Comment: Thanks Yuval. I could have thought a bit more to my question since I knew Berkowitz's algorithm... By the way, I did not know Soltys' paper, thus thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Note that in our paper it is not a direct construction of a quasipolynomial formula for the determinant, but rather a simple recursive construction of a polynomial-size arithmetic circuit with division gates for the determinant. This then results in an $NC^2$-circuit (and quasipolynomial size formula) only after using elimination of division gates and balancing the circuit to have $\log^2(n)$ depth.